# MapKit how to get the Bezier path of a State

Tags: xcode6, mapkit

When i look at apple's Map, I can see the different bezier path of a specific place. I would like to know how to extact that information directly from the map. So let's say the user selects New York, I would like to highlight NEW York's Bezier path directly on the map. can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an alternative form of data that ideally is very close to or exactly the same as the border being drawn by MapKit. You aren't going to get this from Apple.

Take a look at this blog post, where I accomplish the same thing with an open source framework (Mapbox GL) on the web:

http://justinmiller.io/posts/2015/01/20/anatomy-of-a-travel-map/

The ability to highlight areas like this should work in the iOS version of the toolkit as well (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-cocoa) though you will not be able to do the interactivity directly in that framework.